# Does Newton's law of cooling work for forced convection?

Tags: cooling, fluid-dynamics

Does Newton's law of cooling work for forced convection, what extra parameters do I have to consider in the law then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, but with the usual provisos that it is an approximate law and contains a constant that has to be experimentally determined. That is the rate of cooling is given by:

$$ \frac{dT}{dt} \approx -k(T - T_0) $$

where $k$ is the experimentally determined constant. The value of $k$ will be greater for forced convection than for natural convection.